# Text box controls a combo box, default value in the text box does not control it unless user retypes it

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So daily I import some data from SAP. That brings in 6 fields. One of those fields populates a text box (txtStore) on a form. A combo box further down on the form compares the store number to the vendors that store uses on a separate table.

The trouble is this.

The import populates the store number. Lets call it "3". Store 3 corresponds to vendors "e", "f" and "g". But when the user opens the form it lists vendors as "a", "b" and "c" which correspond to the first record in the vendors table. If the user deletes and retypes "3" the correct vendors appear.

How do I make the correct vendors appear when the form is opened automatically?

The code for the combo is as follows:

```
Private Sub txtStore_AfterUpdate()
    cboIP.RowSource = "Select IP from Vendors where (Store=" \& [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore] & ")"
    cboIP.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put that kind of code into one of the form events.

e.g, the `OnLoad` event (assuming txtStore is being populated when it opens as well).